# System Monitor does not launch

Tags: 18.04, system-monitor

My PC has Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

It does not want to launch the System Monitor.

This seems to be an OS related issue. I have launched it before and it worked fine. Possibly due to some updates it has stopped working.

I am not looking for a solution. I just wanted to report this and I hope the issue will be remedied soon with an update.

I would like to know whether other people have the same issue with 18.04.

---

**More info:**

- I try to launch it via:
  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, open System Monitor. No errors. For a few seconds the "loading circle" tries to convince me that there is an attempt to launch it. But then it disappears and nothing happens.
- I am not sure whether this is the command to open from the terminal, but when I run `gnome-system-monitor`, it tells me:

> ```
> /snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/bin/desktop-launch: line 23: /home/sandu/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
> You need to connect this snap to the gnome platform snap.
>
> You can do this with those commands:
> snap install gnome-3-26-1604
> snap connect gnome-system-monitor:gnome-3-26-1604 gnome-3-26-1604
>
> (the '3-26-1604' number defines the platform version and might change)
> ```

Comment: how do you try to launch it ?

Comment: Updated description.

Comment: The error message says what you need to do, run the following commands:
`snap install gnome-3-26-1604` and 
`snap connect gnome-system-monitor:gnome-3-26-1604 gnome-3-26-1604`.

Comment: Yes, but please understand my frustration: it worked fine before. It should work fine without me moving a finger. Why is it that it has stopped working? Why do I have System Monitor in the Applications if it does not even launch?
This looks like a bug to me. A minor one, but it is.

Comment: The issue is Ubuntu shipped snap version of system monitor with 18.04. This issue is specifically due that decision. If you want a hassle-free fix, consider removing the snap version (`snap remove gnome-system-monitor`) and install the traditional one (`sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor`).

Comment: Also this site is *not* the right place for complaints and bug reports as we're in general not Ubuntu developers or Canonical staff, we're just a community of Ubuntu users. Bugs should be reported as launchpad.net.

Comment: Will keep that in mind for the future. I suspected that Ubuntu developers peek from time to time at the issues here. Thank you.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As suggested from comments:

```
snap remove gnome-system-monitor
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```

worked for me.

Comment: It worked. Snap behaves strangely when the home directory is nonstandard (e.g. not /home/username)

Comment: This did not work for me. I still have the same error. More info here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275959/gnome-system-monitor-does-not-launch-even-after-apt-installation

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. The `gnome-system-monitor` is now available as a snap and it appears an update either broke something or didn't change everything properly (I don't really know why it stopped working).

A solution is to reinstall the snap (using `snap`, not `apt`) with:

```bsh
snap remove gnome-system-monitor
snap install gnome-system-monitor
```

Doing this will install/connect the System Monitor properly and it will work once again from both icon and terminal.

Comment: reinstalling it via `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor` worked fine on my machine.. interestingly, `gnome-system-monitor` was in the known/installed apps I can run (it got autocompleted by my terminal) but when I did `apt-cache policy gnome-system-monitor`, it reported it's not installed at all. Then I installed it and it works fine (except it's the "old" one with the old icon.. fine by me)

Answer (score 2):

If `sudo snap get gnome-system-monitor` gives an error, probably something went wrong during the upgrade, thus just do:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-system-monitor
```

and reboot.

Comment: it worked, without system reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Is some package-dependency not solved ?
For system-monitor there is package rsyslog (or rsyslogd?) necessary.

You should install it with:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall rsyslog
```

Am not sure if this is today correct, because this was a while ago necessary. You might check further dependencies here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/gnome-system-monitor

Maybe a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall <package>` helps and then reboot your machine.