# Gnome-system-monitor does not launch even after apt installation

Tags: 18.04, apt, gnome

As instructed in other SO questions ([Clicking on the system monitor button does not work anymore from one day to the next (Ubuntu 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058453/clicking-on-the-system-monitor-button-does-not-work-anymore-from-one-day-to-the) or [System Monitor does not launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045519/system-monitor-does-not-launch?rq=1)) I have installed the apt version of gnome-system-monitor, but I still get an error when my computer is using a lot of its memory and CPU. I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
~$ gnome-system-monitor 

(gnome system-monitor:6179): glibmm-CRITICAL **: 01:14:23.561: 
unhandled exception (type Glib::Error) in signal handler:
domain: g-io-error-quark
code  : 0
what  : Unable to find default local file monitor type
```

Further, I have also tried to follow advice [on the launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bug/1430068) to run `echo 512 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances` to no avail

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks